# Setting up Sublime Text 2 Custom Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm a Vim user trying to move to Sublime Text 2, as it's faster than MacVim with a bunch of stuff open.

I have may custom keyboard shortcuts in Vim, that I would like to transfer to ST2.

How can I set up custom shortcuts? Is there an equivalent to vimrc?

I know I can do some chording shortcuts via the OS X Preferences, but they won't respect the command mode in ST2.

For example, I want to set ^w l to move the input focus one column/pane to the right, and ^w h to move to the left.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Custom key bindings:
Open `Preferences > Key Bindings-Default` read through or search for the binding you want to change.  Copy the command and then open `Preferences > Key Bindings-User`.  Paste and edit the command.

To change the bindings for switching panes, edit these commands.  Notice how keys are separated by `+` and the end of each line (except the last) needs a comma.  I'm not sure if you can set it up so you can move to right/left panes.  The way I set it up is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> switches to the first pane, etc.

```
// panes
{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 0 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+2"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 1 } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+3"], "command": "focus_group", "args": { "group": 2 } }
```

More info: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html

Answer (score 1):

To add to @d_rail's answer,

You can create a simple (ex:<kbd>f12</kbd>), combination (ex: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) and complex (ex: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) shortcut keys as long as you know the command name of the operation.

See here to know more: [Complete list of Sublime Text 3 commands](http://codezag.com/list-sublime-text-3-commands/)